# User defined calendar table in power bi

Tags: calendar, powerbi, relationship, star-schema, table-relationships

I am trying to add calendar table in power bi .. here how i add

```
    Calender = ADDCOLUMNS(CALENDAR (DATE(1995,5,1), DATE(2019,12,31)),
"Year",FORMAT([Date],"YYYY"),"Quarter","Q" &FORMAT([Date],"Q"),
"Month",FORMAT([Date],"MM"),"MonthName",FORMAT([Date],"MMM"),"Monthnumber", FORMAT ([Date], "MM" ),
"YearMonthnumber", FORMAT ( [Date], "YYYY/MM" ),
"YearMonthShort", FORMAT ( [Date], "YYYY/mmm" ),
"MonthNameShort", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmm" ),
"MonthNameLong", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmmm" ),
"DayOfWeekNumber", WEEKDAY ( [Date] ),
"DayOfWeek",FORMAT ( [Date], "dddd" ),
"DayOfWeekShort", FORMAT ( [Date], "ddd" ),
"YearQuarter", FORMAT ( [Date], "YYYY" ) & "/Q" & FORMAT ( [Date], "Q" ))
```

check this picture

[image: image1]

and these are more tables

[image: moretables]

now i want to ask how i add and link datekey in orders_Fact table  where there is no column of datekey in fact table.. i manually create it by query .. when i click on edit queries from home tab then i did not find calendar table in this panel

[image: edit queries]

this is the file link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdsf0xhogr4opgr/test_fle.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Your calendar table is created by DAX and indeed is not visible in "edit query" view. 
I would check if the calendar is on the right of the relationship view of the Power Query Editor (scroll right)
Otherwise try to create the relationship between OrderDate of the facts table & Date in calendar table with the "manage relationship" in ribbons pane.

Comment: but when i search on google north-wind star schema then there is already order-date in fact table and with that there is separate datekey which is linked with calendar table.. so this means order date and datekey is totally different.